# How to find average intensity of OpenCV contour in realtime

Tags: c++, opencv, real-time, average, contour

I have a image with about 50 to 100 small contours. I wish to find the average intensity[1] of each of these contours in real-time[2]. Some of the ways I could think of was

1. Draw contour with FILLED option for each contour; use each image as a mask over the original image, thus find the average. But I presume that this method won't be real-time at first glance.
2. Study OpenCV implementation of `drawContour` function with the FILLED option and access the pixels enclosed by the contour in the same manner. But the code seems really complex and not readily understandable.
3. Calculate the minimum area rectangle, find all the points inside the rectangle using transformation, and find average of points that are non-zero. Again, seems complex approach.

Is there an easier, efficient way to do this?

[1] Average of all pixel intensities enclosed by each of the non-overlapping contours

[2] About 25, (960 x 480) pixel images per sec on a 2.66 Ghz desktop PC

Comment: can you guarantee that your contours are non-overlapping?

Comment: also, what varies in time here? The contours? the images? both?

Comment: If you want to find the "avg color" of each contour, I think the first thing you have to consider is whether you could find those contours(overlapping?) with high accuracy rate anytime any environment in real time.

Comment: Are you trying to find the average value of each contour itself, or of the area enclosed by the contour?

Comment: @Hammer Yes, the contours are non-overlapping. The images vary with time, hence the contours that are calculated from the image vary too.

Comment: @Aureliues and flankechen, I'm able to find those contours in real time. I have a vector of points representing each contour. I wish to find the average intensity of the pixels enclosed by each of the contours. The contours are all closed and non overlapping.

Comment: I can't think of anything simple that would be faster than 1 sorry

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I was unable to come up with any methods substantially different than your suggested approaches. However, I was able to do some timings that may help guide your decision. All of my timings were run on a 1280*720 image on an iMac, limited to finding 100 contours. The timings will of course be different on your machine, but the relative timings should be informative.

For each test case, the following are declared:

```
std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point>> cont;  // Filled by cv::findContours()
cv::Mat labels = cv::Mat::zeros(image.size(), CV_8UC1);     
std::vector<float> cont_avgs(cont.size(), 0.f); // This contains the averages of each contour
```

#### Method 1: 19.0ms

Method 1 is conceptually the simplest, but it is also the slowest. Each contour is labeled by assigning a unique color to each contour. Values of each labelled component are summed by iterating through every pixel in the image.

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < cont.size(); ++i)
{
    // Labels starts at 1 because 0 means no contour
    cv::drawContours(labels, cont, i, cv::Scalar(i+1), CV_FILLED);
}

std::vector<float> counts(cont.size(), 0.f);
const int width = image.rows;
for (size_t i = 0; i < image.rows; ++i)
{
    for (size_t j = 0; j < image.cols; ++j)
    {
        uchar label = labels.data[i*width + j];

        if (label == 0)
        {
            continue;   // No contour
        }
        else
        {
            label -= 1; // Make labels zero-indexed
        }

        uchar value = image.data[i*width + j];
        cont_avgs[label] += value;
        ++counts[label];
    }
}
for (size_t i = 0; i < cont_avgs.size(); ++i)
{
    cont_avgs[i] /= counts[i];
}
```

#### Method 3: 15.7ms

An unmodified Method 3 has the simplest implementation and is also the fastest. All contours are filled to use as a mask for finding the mean. The bounding rectangle of each contour is computed, and then the mean is calculated using the mask within the bounding box.

**Warning:** This method will give incorrect results if any other contours are within the bounding rectangle of the contour of interest.

```
cv::drawContours(labels, cont, -1, cv::Scalar(255), CV_FILLED);

for (size_t i = 0; i < cont.size(); ++i)
{
    cv::Rect roi = cv::boundingRect(cont[i]);
    cv::Scalar mean = cv::mean(image(roi), labels(roi));
    cont_avgs[i] = mean[0];
}
```

#### Modified Method 3: 17.8ms

Making slight modifications to Method 3 increases execution time slightly, but gains the benefit of giving correct results regardless of contour positions. Each contour is individually labeled, and the mean is calculated using only the mask for that contour.

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < cont.size(); ++i)
{
    cv::drawContours(labels, cont, i, cv::Scalar(i), CV_FILLED);
    cv::Rect roi = cv::boundingRect(cont[i]);
    cv::Scalar mean = cv::mean(image(roi), labels(roi) == i);
    cont_avgs[i] = mean[0];
}
```

Comment: Very useful analysis! I like your modified method 3 over mine. I will use this for now and also try and learn how OpenCV implements the CV_FILLED option of drawContours for comparison. Thanks!