# Finding the Average Color within a Polygon Bound in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

### Background

I am trying to create a utility that will return the average pixel color within a given polygon using `OpenCV`. The polygon will be defined via 4 points, but it is not necessarily a rectangle/square. For example, the following structures are to be expected:

```
     A__________B    A_______B
    /          /     \       \
   /          /       \       \
 D/__________/C       D\_______\C
```

---

Given a `cv::Mat` image in OpenCV and a polygon defined by the points (A, B, C, D). I know points A, B, C, and D, but I want to calc the average pixel color within the polygon. I wanted to get some suggestions from the OpenCV community on how to do this most efficiently.

---

### Research Done

Another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17956767/3342427) on StackOverflow suggested drawing contours using the [`drawContours`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=drawcontours#drawcontours) function and then take the [`mean`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#mean) of the bounding rectangle surrounding the contour. I would obviously have to modify the mean calculation so that it uses the polygons drawn by the [`fillPoly`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#fillpoly) function instead.

Suggestions/Concerns are much appreciated!

Comment: Also note that in the answer you linked, the mean is not computed on the bounding box, but on the polygon mask. The bounding box is used only to focus on the part of the mask where the polygon really is (which can be a good optimization).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can simply use the [mean](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#mean) function with a mask, where the mask is your filled polygon.

```
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    // Create a black image with a gray rectangle on top left
    Mat1b img(300, 300, uchar(0));
    rectangle(img, Rect(0, 0, 100, 100), Scalar(100), CV_FILLED);

    // Define a polygon
    Point pts[1][4];
    pts[0][0] = Point(20, 20);
    pts[0][1] = Point(40, 100);
    pts[0][2] = Point(200, 60);
    pts[0][3] = Point(150, 30);

    const Point* points[1] = {pts[0]};
    int npoints = 4;

    // Create the mask with the polygon
    Mat1b mask(img.rows, img.cols, uchar(0));
    fillPoly(mask, points, &npoints, 1, Scalar(255));

    // Compute the mean with the computed mask
    Scalar average = mean(img, mask);

    std::cout << average << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So if I have multiple polygons I want to use ask a mask (one at a time), then I would have populate the `pts` variable up to numPolygons, and then iterate over each of the polygons and create the mask for that polygon. Correct?

Comment: In theory yes, however I think that you cannot specify in `fillPoly` to draw the n-th polygon. So I think is better to fill `pts` with one polygon at the time, and draw only that single polygon into `fillPoly`.

Comment: Sounds great. Thanks!

Comment: Is this approach not very inefficient? 
Coloring a polygon is not an insignificant task. Moreover, if the Mat is very large and the polygon a small rectangle is not more efficient to access all the values in the rectangle by index and calculate the mean?

Comment: @DavidSackstein 1) it's not a rectangle, but a polygon. So you need a way to find which point is inside the polygon. cv::fillPolygon is a good choice, since it creates a mask that can be fed to cv::mean. 2) This question is not about performance 3) If you are talking about performance, you need to profile your use case. This approach may not be the best, but it's hardly the bottleneck of you application. 4) You can work on a smaller roi, but it depends on your use case. 5) You can post you answer if you have a better one ;)

Comment: @Miki I think your comment about applying this technique to the bounding box of the polygon rather than applying it to the entire image addresses my concern.