# OpenCV create advanced mask from 4 points

Tags: python, opencv, crop

Idea seems simple in theory but I completely don't know how to approach it.
I have an image/frame, and given 4 points to draw polygon.

Each side has to  x smaller polygons and then I need mean colour or average colour of that smaller polygons.
So purple is the whole frame, red points are the points given and defined, and grey polygons are calculated based on how many I want per side, so this example top and bottom needs 6 and sides 5. (they should be even). And then I need mean colour of each grey polygons.
Now it was easy when everything is rectangular and I can just use crop, but because I am new to opencv I completely don't know how to approach that problem. Any hints would be much appreciated

[image]

Comment: Have a look at [fillConvexPoly](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/89412/cv2.fillConvexPoly) or [fillPoly](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/89415/cv2.fillPoly)

Comment: Count the 4 points of each polygons should be easy, then try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32466616/finding-the-average-color-within-a-polygon-bound-in-opencv)